# How to fix ValueError: multiclass format is not supported

Tags: python, scikit-learn, spyder, roc

This is my code and I try to calculate ROC score but I have a problem with ValueError: multiclass format is not supported. I'm already looking sci-kit learn but it doesn't help. In the end, I'm still have ValueError: multiclass format is not supported.

This is my code

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix,zero_one_loss
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,matthews_corrcoef,accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score, auc


dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier()
bc = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=dtc, n_estimators=10, random_state=17)
bc.fit(train_x, train_Y)
pred_y = bc.predict(test_x)

fprate, tprate, thresholds = roc_curve(test_Y, pred_y)
results = confusion_matrix(test_Y, pred_y)
error = zero_one_loss(test_Y, pred_y)
roc_auc_score(test_Y, pred_y)

FP = results.sum(axis=0) - np.diag(results)  
FN = results.sum(axis=1) - np.diag(results)
TP = np.diag(results)
TN = results.sum() - (FP + FN + TP)



print('\n Time Processing: \n',time.process_time())
print('\n Confussion Matrix: \n', results)
print('\n Zero-one classification loss: \n', error)
print('\n True Positive: \n', TP)
print('\n True Negative: \n', TN)
print('\n False Positive: \n', FP)
print('\n False Negative: \n', FN)
print ('\n The Classification report:\n',classification_report(test_Y,pred_y, digits=6))
print ('MCC:', matthews_corrcoef(test_Y,pred_y))
print ('Accuracy:', accuracy_score(test_Y,pred_y))
print (auc(fprate, tprate))
print ('ROC Score:', roc_auc_score(test_Y,pred_y))
```

This is the traceback

[image]

Comment: Please add error message with it so we can able to trace line no and message

Comment: Yeah I already put the error in the question

Comment: Can you post the full traceback so we can see what line in your code is causing the error? As of now it only shows where the error is happening in the sci-kit learn library which is not particularly helpful

Comment: okay I already put it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the docs, [roc_curve](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html?highlight=roc_curve#sklearn.metrics.roc_curve): "Note: this implementation is restricted to the binary classification task."

Are your label classes (y) either `1` or `0`? If not, I think you have to add the `pos_label` parameter to your `roc_curve` call.

```
fprate, tprate, thresholds = roc_curve(test_Y, pred_y, pos_label='your_label')
```

Or:

```
test_Y = your_test_y_array  # these are either 1's or 0's
fprate, tprate, thresholds = roc_curve(test_Y, pred_y)
```

Answer (score 2):

`pos_label` is set to `1`, if not will be error

```
fprate, tprate, thresholds = roc_curve(test_Y, pred_y, pos_label=1)
```